# Xcode10 error: can't exec (No such file or directory) for a user defined build setting

Tags: ios, xcode, good-dynamics, blackberry-dynamics

I get the "error: can't exec (No such file or directory)" when building a project with a user-defined build setting which is a path to a script. The project builds in Xcode 9.

```
ld = $(USER_LIBRARY_DIR)/Application\ Support/BlackBerry/Good.platform/iOS/FIPS_module/$FIPS_PACKAGE/bin/gd_fipsld
```

gives

```
error: can't exec '/Users/username/Library/Application\ Support/BlackBerry/Good.platform/iOS/FIPS_module/arm64.sdk/bin/gd_fipsld' (No such file or directory)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xcode10 the new build system doesn’t support the tilde(~) character which is replaced with $(HOME) in the path.

```
Before: ~/Library/Application Support/BlackBerry/Good.platform/iOS/FIPS_module/$FIPS_PACKAGE/bin/gd_fipsld

After: $(HOME)/Library/Application Support/BlackBerry/Good.platform/iOS/FIPS_module/$FIPS_PACKAGE/bin/gd_fipsld
```

*Note: The changes needs to be made in default.xcconfig file.*